# Write into CSV, row by row using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement, where i need to generate a number with year and month(concatenated), and write the same numbers into csv, which should be in row by row, tried below code,

```
import csv

l = []
for x in range(2019,2031):
    for i in range(1,13):
        m = str(x)+str(i)
        l.append(m)
        #l.append('\n')
    writer = csv.writer(open("path\\test.csv","w"))
    writer.writerows([l])
```

But i'm getting values in single row, not row by row(in single column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `writerow()`.

```
import csv

l = []
for x in range(2019,2031):
    for i in range(1,13):
        m = str(x)+str(i)
        l.append(m)
writer = csv.writer(open("path\\test.csv","w",newline=''))
for each in l:
    writer.writerow([each])
```

Comment: Tried your code, got values row by row, however, after every row i'm getting empty row.

20191

20192

20193

20194

20195

Comment: just add `newline=''` to `open`. I am editing the code